# Merge tools in "Resolve conflicts" not shown in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2019

I'm using VS 2019 and working with an ASP.NET MVC project.

I got merge conflicts that had to be resolved manually. The problem is that the button for “Merge changes in merge tool” at the top of the VS editor - is not shown.

I've seen this issue happened since 2019 and it seems that it still doesn't fix it completely...

Answer (score 5):

Also inconvenient when met with the same issue.

**You can try below method:**

Open vs 2019 (The specific vs 2019 version used: Visual Studio Professional 2019 Version `16.10.0`):

**Menu** -> **Git** -> **Settings** =>

**Source control** -> **Git Global Settings** -> "Tools"

Click "Visual studio" for the option of "Diff Tool" and "Merge tool" respectively.

May it be helpful for you. Just enjoy!

[image: git settings for vs 2019]

Comment: Didn't work for me. Left it changed though. Thanks!

Comment: Didn't work for us, either. But we had started a merge conflict, so I'm wondering if since a merge conflict was already initiated, VS couldn't incorporate the Merge Editor? And why doesn't Microsoft turn this feature on by default?

Comment: Any luck ? I tried the above mentioned steps but still merging is not working on my visual studio. I posted similar question but got no answer

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this issue by `un-check` the `optimize rendering for screens with different pixel densities`.

Go Tools --> Options and in `General` tab of `Environment` section and `un-check` the second item.

[image]

Based on [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/merge-tools-in-resolve-conflicts-not-shown/499815), it seems that this issue has been fixed in latest version.

Comment: Didn't work for me.

Comment: @JamesBailey Restart your Visual Studio please.

Comment: Ya, that was my 1st thought too. I had already tried that and rebooting prior to commenting. It appears this is a Visual studio plugin that has bee vexing Microsoft for years. I have 2 other developers that have the same issue. We are on VS2022 (latest)

Comment: @JamesBailey - I have the same issue using VS 17.4. Did you ever manage to find a solution to this annoying problem?